# Pasting specific data on a new sheet with macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a hospital spreadsheet with data, where the data is organised depending on age, sex, Health Authority etc. Like this:[image: data]

Where "sha" means the Health Authority, and each number corresponds to a certain one.
1-Norfolk, Suffolk and Cambridgeshire
2-Bedforshire & Hertfordshire
and so on until Health Authority number 28

I am creating a macro that opens a new sheet, and I need to only paste the data of the patients from a certain Health authority previously selected from a drop-down box.

I have already created the macro that creates the new sheet (i'll paste the code here), but now I need to paste all the data of the patients **only if** they belong to the health authority selected from the drop-down box.
This is my code so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub createsheet()

   Dim sName As String, ws As Worksheet
   sName = Sheets("user").Range("M42").Value
   
   ' check if already exists
   On Error Resume Next
   Set ws = Sheets(sName)
   On Error GoTo 0
   
   If ws Is Nothing Then
       ' ok add
       Set ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
       ws.Name = sName
       MsgBox "Sheet created : " & ws.Name, vbInformation
   Else
       ' exists
       MsgBox "Sheet '" & sName & "' already exists", vbCritical, "Error"
   End If
   
End Sub
```

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can call this sub from your sub like:
`Transfer_to_NewSheet ws, SHA`
Where SHA is the SHA number from whatever drop down you're using.
I'm sure you can figure out how to do that.

Also remember to change:
`Set Master = Worksheets("Main")`
to whatever your data sheet is called.

```
Sub Transfer_to_NewSheet(WS As Worksheet, SHA)

    Dim Master As Worksheet
    Dim DataRG As Range
    Dim InArray
    Dim OutArray
    Dim I As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim X As Long
    Dim W As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim SHAcol As Long

    ' Or whatever your master sheet is called
    Set Master = Worksheets("Main")
    
    With Master
        lCol = .Range("ZZ1").End(xlToLeft).Column
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        SHAcol = .Range("A1").Resize(1, lCol).Find(What:="sha", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        Set DataRG = .Range("A1").Resize(lRow, lCol)
    End With
    
    InArray = DataRG
    ReDim OutArray(1 To lRow, 1 To lCol)
    
    Y = 1
    For I = 1 To UBound(InArray, 1)
        If InArray(I, SHAcol) = SHA Or I = 1 Then
            For X = 1 To UBound(InArray, 2)
                OutArray(Y, X) = InArray(I, X)
            Next X
            Y = Y + 1
        End If
    Next I
    
    WS.Range("A1").Resize(lRow, lCol) = OutArray
    
End Sub
```

This is the Data I used to test:

[image]

This is the output I get from `SHA = 12`

[image]

And this is the sub I was using to call it, just for reference. don't use it.

```
Sub CallWSxfer()
    
    Dim SHA As Long
    
    ' Or pull it from whatever drop down you're using...
    SHA = InputBox("Enter SHA Number:", "SHA to New Sheet", "01")

    Transfer_to_NewSheet Sheet4, SHA
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using the code, and I added the code: Set Master = Worksheets("Main") under the sub Transfer_to_NewSheet(WS As Worksheet, SHA). However it does not put the data in the new sheet. The sheet where I have my drop-down box is called "user" and the data is on the sheet called "data". Do you know what am I missing?

Comment: Okay, change the line `Set Master = Worksheets("Main")` to `Set Master = Worksheets("Data")` and when calling `Transfer_to_NewSheet ` you need to "pass" my sub the new worksheet like: `Set ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)) <br> ws.Name = sName <br> Transfer_to_NewSheet ws, [sha number]`

Comment: You'll need to pull your sha number in like: `worksheets("user").range("[dropdownboxrange").value`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `AutoFilter()` method of `Range` object:

assuming:

- data have headers in row 10 from column 1 rightwards and don't have blank rows/columns in between
- the searched SHA will always be found in data column F

you could place this snippet right after your `MsgBox "Sheet created : " & ws.Name, vbInformation` code line

```
   With Sheets("data")
        With .Range("A10").CurrentRegion 

            .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=sName
            .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Range("A1")
            
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
   End With
```

Comment: An error pops out when I paste the code there. When I click debug it highlights this line of code:    .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=sName

Comment: Did you place it in your posted code and _exactly_ where I told you? And what is the error message?

Comment: It says "Run-time error 1004 Auto-filter method of range class failed". I put the code right between "MsgBox "Sheet created : " & ws.Name, vbInformation" and the else statement

Comment: I got from a comment of yours that the data sheet is named after “data”: I changed my code accordingly

Comment: I jus added the code and it still does not paste the data, only the sheet is being created...

Comment: Add a screenshot of your data sheet so as to see actual data layout